# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "A lo mejor"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia

Esta expresión tiene el siguiente significado:

> [a lo mejor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OnhZjCP)
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Quizá, tal vez.

Su uso es claro, pero si pienso mucho en la frase no le veo mucho sentido. Me pregunto si esa frase hacía parte de otra más larga que tuviera más significado que la actual.

Answer (score 6):

Parece que no formaba parte de ninguna frase más larga, sino que debía interpretarse como "en el mejor de los casos" o "en el mejor momento".

Veo muchos casos de "a lo mejor" en textos de antes del siglo XVI pero con esos textos ya he aprendido a tener cuidado. Por ejemplo, según el CORDE veo un caso de "a lo mejor" en *El conde Lucanor*, del siglo XIV, pero revisando [el manuscrito original](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/el-conde-lucanor-manuscrito--0/html/00919b9e-82b2-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_145.htm) no he visto rastro de esa expresión. A partir del siglo XVIII es cuando veo ejemplos próximos a lo que podría ser el uso actual:

> *Voy a servir a vmd., mi señor don Eusebio, pero a lo mejor me rompió vmd. el discurso.*

Este ejemplo de 1786 usa "a lo mejor" como "en el mejor momento". De hecho, la primera vez que se recoje "a lo mejor" en el diccionario de la RAE de 1869 tiene este significado:

> Á LO MEJOR. fr. fam. con que se anuncia algun hecho ó dicho inesperado, y por lo comun infausto ó desagradable.

Es decir, en plan "estaba yo en lo mejor cuando alguien vino a importunarme". Antes, en 1846, el *Salvá* lo recogía así:

> Á LO MEJOR. mod. adv. Cuando menos se espera.

Este sentido de "en el mejor de los casos" se sigue atestiguando durante el siglo XIX, usando la expresión seguida de hechos nefastos:

> *... las calles que a lo mejor acababan en un corral sin salida...
>
>   Si a lo mejor se nos mete aquí una señora bomba y nos coge en la cama y en paños menores...
>
>   ... y a lo mejor nos asusta por las noches despertando despavorida...*

En todo caso, se va notando ya que la expresión va cogiendo la idea de "existe la posibilidad de que ocurra algo", más que la idea de "seguro que algo me fastidia el mejor momento" o "en el mejor de los casos". Pero no fue hasta 1984 que cambió la definición del diccionario de la RAE:

> **a lo mejor.** loc. adv. fam. con que se enuncia la incertidumbre o posibilidad de algo.